# Clearing many textbox controls in vb.net at once

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am using the following code to clear the

```
txtint1.Clear()
txtext1.Clear()
txttot1.Clear()
txtint2.Clear()
txtext2.Clear()
txttot2.Clear()
txtint3.Clear()
txtext3.Clear()
txttot3.Clear()
txtint4.Clear()
txtext4.Clear()
txttot4.Clear()
txtint5.Clear()
txtext5.Clear()
txttot5.Clear()
txtint6.Clear()
txtext6.Clear()
txttot7.Clear()
txtint8.Clear()
txtext8.Clear()
txttot8.Clear()
```

Is there any possibility to clear all the textbox controls at once or with few lines of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms Clearing multiple Textboxes with one command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217101/winforms-clearing-multiple-textboxes-with-one-command)

Comment: Having textboxes with random names like that introduces a bigger maintenance concern than clearing them using the above method. You need to refactor the names and their hierarchy. Ideally, there should be a reference to all those controls from the parent, so you don't need to recursively traverse Controls tree every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put them in an array then loop through the array:

```
For Each txt In {txtint1, txtext1, txttot1, txtint2, txtext2, txttot2, txtint3, txtext3, txttot3, txtint4, txtext4, txttot4, txtint5, txtext5, txttot5, txtint6, txtext6, txttot7, txtint8, txtext8, txttot8}
    txt.Clear()
Next
```

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that this is better, clearer, or more maintainable than the original code...

Comment: The question didn't specify whether clearing all textbox controls or just a specific set was required. Prash answered the former, I answered the latter. It's up to the OP to pick which answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate over all controls on the form which are contained in `root.Controls` and see if it is of type a textbox `TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox`, then you can clear the text in that control `CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty`

Well!! You need to use recursion to loop through all controls

**Adding the code:**

```
Public Sub ClearTextBox(parent As Control)

    For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
        ClearTextBox(child)
    Next

    If TryCast(parent, TextBox) IsNot Nothing Then
        TryCast(parent, TextBox).Text = [String].Empty
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Very streamlined and readable solution in comparison to what I've come across in my research. Allowing the parent to be set as a parameter is a great bonus and the method is furthermore, readily adaptable for including other control types. e.g. [Combo Boxes](http://pastebin.com/wxSFNYeD).

Answer (score 4):

I tried one of the examples here but this seems to work for me:

```
Dim a As Control
    For Each a In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
            a.Text = Nothing
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This is my favourite answer on this thread. The recursive solution is neat, but this is the fewest lines of code and requires no recursion.

Comment: Simple and short, I like it!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
   txt.Text = ""
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    Dim a As Control
    For Each a In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
            a.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
```

or

```
Dim a As Control
    For Each a In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
            a.clear()
        End If
    Next
```

if .Clear() is a member of textbox property then use it. i guess .clear() is not a member of textbox properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that I personally use it in my projects  ^_^

`ClearAll TextBoxes :
        For Each TxtBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            TxtBox.Clear()
        Next TxtBox`

Answer (score 0):

I had to cast the Control as a TextBox to make this work. Something about the control object not being accessible. There may be a more direct way but I was unable to find one.

I got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16264904/11242863

```
Private Sub clearAllTextBoxes()
    Dim formControl As Control
    Dim txtBox As TextBox
    For Each formControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf formControl Is TextBox Then
            txtBox = TryCast(formControl, TextBox)
            txtBox.Clear()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone,

Tim R

Answer (score 0):

This Will Reset All controls on Form To Default Value

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Controls.Clear()
    InitializeComponent()
    Form1_Load(Me, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and the best code I have used:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Controls.Clear()
    InitializeComponent()
    Form1_Load(Me, Nothing)
End Sub
```